# During AJAX call of POST method converted to GET method when using with Django i18n pattern

Tags: jquery, django, python-3.x, ajax, django-i18n

I have used Django i18n pattern in my project to convert my website text between english and german.

I have handled all post methods with common code written in webbase.js file.

After implementation of Django i18n code in my project, my website started to behave strangely and converted my all POST mehtod with GET.

I have already tried with solutions explained online like below.
sol-1 : Append slash after url.
sol-2 : AJAX call I have tried with both `type: "POST"` ad `method: "POST"`.

But even after updating code as per solution, still I am not able to solve my issue.

My code is as below.

**webbase.js**

```
app.post = function(url, postData, hasMsg, callback, dataType, msgId, processData, contentType) {
    try {
      msgId = msgId || "appMsg"
      var ajaxParam = {
        dataType: dataType || "json",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": app.getStorage("csrftoken")
        },
        url:url,
        data: postData,
        beforeSend: function() {
          ajaxCalls++;
          $('#loading-image').show();
        },
        complete: function() {
          ajaxCalls--;
          if(ajaxCalls == 0) {
            $('#loading-image').hide();
          }
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (hasMsg) {
            if (data.code == 0) {
              app.showMessage(msgId, app.MsgType.Error, data.msg, 10);
              return;
            }

            app.showMessage(msgId, app.MsgType.Success, data.msg, 10);
          }

          if(callback) {
            callback(data);
          }
        },
        error: function(data) {
          app.showMessage(msgId, app.MsgType.Error, "Error occurred", 10);
          console.log(data);
        }  
      }

      if(typeof processData !== typeof undefined) {
        ajaxParam['processData'] = processData;
      }

      if(typeof contentType !== typeof undefined) {
        if(!contentType) {
          ajaxParam['contentType'] = contentType;
        }
      }

      $.ajax(ajaxParam);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  };
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path("", include('website.urls')),
    path("website/", include('website.urls')),prefix_default_language=True)
```

Below are screenshot of POST method before applying i18n pattern code.
[image: Post method]
[image: Post method response]

Below are screenshot of GET method after applying i18n pattern code.
[image: GET method]
[image: GET method response]

It will be great help if anyone can suggest me proper solution.

Comment: i also have same problem while calling ajax. i think it's problem in **i18n**.